# Are Symfony 2.0 Route Wildcards sanitized?

Tags: php, symfony

...or do I have to sanitized them as below?

```
class RelationshipController extends Controller
{
    ...

    public function deleteAction($objectId)
    {
        $objectId = filter_var($objectId, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT)
        ...
```

Comment: The point of route filters (that you define in YAML config - specifically `[0-9]`) is to avoid filtering yourself. So depends, if you asked a router to match only numbers, you don't have to do that. Otherwise it would be matched as a string, so it would require to do that manually

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, Symfony Router matches route parameters by the following regex: `[^/]+`. So anything except `/` is allowed.

If you want to ensure `$objectId` is an integer you should define a route like so:

```
my_route:
    path: /my/route/{objectId}
    defaults: { _controller: MyBundle:Controller:myAction }
    requirements:
        objectId: \d+
```

This way, your `$objectId` will always be a string representation of an integer because Symfony will not match route if it isn't.

So this will match your controller:

```
GET /my/route/234
```

This will throw 404 not found:

```
GET /my/route/asd
```